# Java variable with write priority

Tags: java, multithreading

I was working on making a thread-safe variable for my robotics team. It contains the value of a sensor and I want to give it write priority. The best solution I could come up with was the following.

20 milliseconds is how often the main loop is going to be called.

```
public class Gyro
{
    static final Thread worker;
    static final BlockingDeque<Thread> queue;
    static volatile double value;

    static
    {
        queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

        worker = new Thread(()
                -> 
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread t = queue.take();
                            t.interrupt();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ex)
                        {
                            //Some kinda error logging
                        }
                    }
        });
        worker.setDaemon(true);
        worker.start();
    }

    public static void updateValue()
    {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        queue.add(t);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            throw new RuntimeException("Gyro value not set in 20 miliseconds");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException expected)
        {
            //set value
            //value = 
        }
    }

    public static double getValue()
    {

        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        queue.addLast(t);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            throw new RuntimeException("Gyro value not obtained in 20 milliseconds");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException expected)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to make a variable with write-priority (ie. thread priority or something) or is this the best solution?

Comment: As hard as this is to understand it's hardly the best solution. What's stopping you from using a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)? That sleep/interrupt design does not look very elegant.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` doesn't necessarily sleep for the exact time that you ask it to sleep for.

Comment: This seems wildly complicated. I can't work out what you're actually intending to do; but there is undoubtedly something in `java.util.concurrent.*` which does what you want more cleanly.

Comment: Are you trying to update a variable every 20 ms is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReentrantReadWriteLock` with *Fair mode*.
From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html):

> A thread that tries to acquire a fair read lock (non-reentrantly) will block if either the write lock is held, or there is a waiting writer thread.

so write is prioritized in fair mode.

Comment: I suppose I need to spend more time reading the documentation. Thanks for taking the time to read what is probably really hard to read code.